# Accordion with up and down arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am trying to create a jQuery accordion with up and down arrows. I am using font awesome angle up and down for this purpose. Everything is going absolutely right the arrow down is shown when accordion is closed and the arrow up is shown when accordion is opened. But the only problem is that it only works when the user clicks over the particular accordion header. When the user clicks another header the arrows don't change.

```js
var toggleHeader = $('.toggle-header');
var toggleContent = $('.toggle-content');

toggleHeader.click(function() {
  toggleHeader.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).find('.toggle-arrow-down').hide();
  $(this).find('.toggle-arrow-up').show();

  if ($(this).next('div').is(':visible')) {
    $(this).next('div').slideUp();
    $(this).find('.toggle-arrow-down').show();
    $(this).find('.toggle-arrow-up').hide();
  } else {
    toggleContent.slideUp();
    $(this).next('div').slideDown();
  }

  return false;
});
```

```css
.toggle-header {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.toggle-header.active {
  background: #ccc;
}

.toggle-header .toggle-switch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="toggle-header">
    <h3> This is toggle title </h3>
    <div class="toggle-switch">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up arrow-up"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down arrow-down"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-content">
      This is the paragraph
    </div>
    <div class="toggle">
      <div class="toggle-header">
        <h3> This is toggle title </h3>
        <div class="toggle-switch">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-up arrow-up"></i>
          <i class=" fa fa-angle-down arrow-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle-content">
          This is the paragraph
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the active items you want to change on the click event, and change them. You could use:

```
var active = $(this).find(".active");
```

in your click function (where `$(this)` is `$('.toggle-header')` ) and then do whatever you want with the arrows and active state etc.

For example `active.removeClass("active").slideUp().find(".toggle-arrow-up").hide();` and so on.

However, I'm thinking the path you're on with this is maybe not the most robust. I would strongly suggest taking a look at the [Ridiculously simple accordion](http://uniondesign.ca/simple-accordion-without-jquery-ui/)
coding example which sets out the simplest possible accordion (html, css and script) and is very useful as a starting point to build in the extra functionality you want.